# Store meridiem in a variable

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code:

```
var myDate= new Date();
myDate.toLocaleString( ); 
var x= myDate.getDay(); 
var y=myDate.gethours();
var z=myDate.getMinutes();
```

The time is in 12 hour format.
Now I need to store meridiem (AM or PM) in a variable. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you must be getting 24 hours format by using getHours() function. please confirm me on this.

Comment: According to MDN, [`Date.getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) returns 24-hour format (`0` to `23`). [`Date.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) returns a formatted string, but you're not using the return value anywhere; it does not do anything to change the underlying `Date` object.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
var y=myDate.getHours();
var meridiem = (y<12)?"AM":"PM";
alert(meridiem)
```

Answer (score 3):

getHours() returns the hour in a 24 hour format. A quick solution would be:

```
var meridiem = (y >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `>=`?  Otherwise you'd have 2 "12AM"s! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Wrapped into a nice tiny function!

```
function getMeridiem()
{
    var d = new Date();
    return (d.getHours() < 12) ? 'AM':'PM';
}
```